# Check form field change on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an html form which has a couple of text boxes and a submit button. I would like to check if the textbox has changed value -- if so, submit it to database, else just redirect to different page.

I was trying the following code. I keep getting the text changed alert even when the text is not changed. I am not sure what is wrong here?

Here is the code that I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/828/

And my html form.

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="myform" id="container">  
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" value="" 
        onkeypress='validate1(event)' 
        onfocus="if (this.className=='hint') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }" 
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.className = 'hint'; this.value = '';}" 
        size="25" maxlength="30"/>   
    <input type="text" id="number1" name="number1" value="" 
        onkeypress='validate(event)' 
        onfocus="if (this.className=='hint') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.className = 'hint'; this.value = '';}" 
        size="20" maxlength="10"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" id="submit" class="button1" />
</form>
<script>
    function validate(evt){
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        if( !regex.test(key) ) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function validate1(evt){
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var regex = /[a-zA-Z]|\./;
        if( !regex.test(key) ) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `$('form').change('submit', ...` can't possibly be what you want. How about `$('form').on('submit', ...` for a start?

Comment: @76484: If I use on...It will alert immediately after any change. I would like to do it only on submit.

Comment: .on('change', ...) will fire on a change event, .on('submit', ...) will fire on a submit event.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I tried what ever you told you me. It doesn't work. The alert comes up even before I submit - http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/832/.

Comment: Also.. The alert comes up even when the text box is not changed. I want to check the field if they changed on submit and then do the process accordingly.

Comment: I do not believe that the get the alert before you submit the form.

Comment: Please check the link: http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/832/ and you will know what I am saying? Thanks!

Comment: I do *not* know what you are saying. The alert is getting called when you submit the form because that's what you've instructed to happen. If you want the input values to be checked for changes (changes from what?), then you must write that validation in your submit handler.

Comment: @76484: Please read my question again, you will understand what I am trying to do.. I would like to check if there are any changes to my text box if so send it Database.php if no changes in text box then send it logout.php. (I have ten text box so I would like to check the changes on submit button.

Comment: What do you mean by "changed"? Does is mean if they are not blank? Or do you want to set an initial 'value' attribute and track whether this has been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is keep track of if any of the textboxes have changed. You can do this using `$elem.data`. Of course, if you have only one form element, you could just use a variable, since we're only storing one thing anyway.

Code:

```
// We keep track of the form to check if it changes
// Initially, none of the forms have changed
$("form").data("changed", false);
// When it changes, set "changed" to true
$("form").on("change", function() {
    $(this).data("changed", true);
});
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    if ($(this).data("changed")) {
        alert("Something changed!");
        // Reset variable
        $(this).data("changed", false);
    } else {
        alert("Nothing changed!");
    }
    // Do whatever you want here
    // You don't have to prevent submission
    return false;
});
```

Side note: JSFiddle has a "scripts" panel dedicated to JavaScript. Don't put your script in the HTML panel. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/xxf08dbz/